# How to edit all values in listbox by read, insert and remove? VB

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

I have a listbox in VB 2010 that needs to multiply all values by a number as typed in a textbox. The value must be read, remove and inserted using a loop.

Thanks

Comment: An example would make things more clear. Does your list box contain only numbers? Are these numbers the initial input for the multilplication? Shall the values in that list box be replaced by the result? And what have you done so far? Please clarify.

Comment: You are on the ball :) ListBox only contains numbers. The numbers in the listbox must me multiplied by the amount typed in the textbox. The values in the listbox should be replaced by the result.

'For vIndex = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
'vCount = ListBox1.Items(vIndex)
'ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(vIndex)
'ListBox1.Items.Insert(vCount, Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox1.Text) * 0.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why remove and reinsert, when you only want to modify the existing values? Try this:

```
    Dim mult = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    For vIndex = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim newVal = Val(ListBox1.Items(vIndex)) * mult
        ListBox1.Items(vIndex) = Trim(Str(newVal))
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to update an item in listbox. Just write the above code at your update button's click event.

```
Dim index As Integer=Listbox1.SelectedIndex
Listbox1.Items.Remove(Listbox1.SelectedItem)
Listbox1.Items.Insert(index,Textbox1.Text)
```

here textbox contains value to be updated. First write the value in textbox. Then select the item u wish to update with the value of textbox and then click the update button to update the item.